# ng2-pdf-viewer | pdf is not displaying for external url which has underscores(_) and hyphens(-) in it

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ng2-pdf-viewer to display pdf documents in angular 6. PDFs are visible using local url(`../assets/documents/Sample-doc.pdf`) with having spaces, underscores and hyphens in it but when I am trying to load pdf using external url(`http://155.200.100.160:8089/files/439928/Sample_Doc.pdf`) with _, - in it then it is not loading and not even coming in `(after-load-complete)` function.

html pdf code:

```
<pdf-viewer class="zoom-file" [src]="viewDocUrl" [rotation]="rotatePdf"  [zoom]="pdf_zoom_to" [page]="documentPageNo" [show-all]="false" #docView *ngIf="documentExtPdf" [render-text]="true" (after-load-complete)="onPdfProgress($event)"></pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Are you able to access one from that URL **without** underscores in?

Comment: Yes, when I hit url in browser it loads fine. Thanks...